# What are Omega's Stats?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I've been searching but can't locate the statistics for Omega, whom you can tame in the Coliseum boss battle (Amazon.com pre-order bonus).

What is his role type? How does he develop (e.g. **Early Learner**, **Late Bloomer**, etc.)? I'm kind of *assuming* that he'll be a **Late Bloomer** but I suppose you never know... What are his final stats and level after fully leveled up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omega is a `COM` with **Late Bloomed** (i.e. max level 99), **Sparkprone**, and **Heartless**.

Passives Abilities: Feral Surge, Feral Fatigue and Leadenstrike.

Starting Attributes:

```
Attack 595
Magic  479
ATB    Level 3
HP     3241
```

Comment: +1 What is his feral link ability, and what does it do?

Comment: It's "Wave Cannon" 
Help says: "Inflict magic damage on target and nearby foes. Input Type: Multiple"

Answer (score 2):

I've been playing for a little while now. My omega is level 64 and it's stats are

- STR 1001 (STR 16% Passive)
- MAG 580
- HP 7412 (HP 25% Passive)

Comment: Does he learn those passives on his own or did you infuse him?

Answer (score 1):

Omega Level   1

```
HP:        3509
Strength:   601
Magic:      483
```

Omega Level  99

```
HP:       10002 (HP+30%)
Strength:  1304 (Strength+35%)
Magic:      994 (Magic+35%)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 - level    85
 - strength 1101
 - magic    709
 - hp       7168
```

aprox 200 level 5 atb for a lvl. 99